# UINavigationController limited utilization in app design

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I am using the NavigationController (Embedded via Editor drop down menu in xCode) to control navigation on sign-up and sign-in views, all from landing view when app first launched.

After user sign-up or login, I would like to initiate a view controller with no relation to the NavigationController. Nonetheless, from Sign-up and Login views, I have a segue that links (upon successful authorization) to the main view of logged in users. How can I remove the navigation controller from a certain part of the application because it is no longer needed? Otherwise, each time I add a new view controller, it shows the navigation bar in it which is not ideal for design.

Thanks and image attached shows what I need illustrated.[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned you can remove only view controller from navigation stack. If you do not want navigation bar to be visible, then just hide it in viewWillAppear of view controller that you want to be without navigationBar.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:<#(BOOL)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#>]
```

Comment: Yes that is what I am doing now. I was asking to see if there is a better way of doing this or avoiding it altogether.

Comment: Hmm...I think you can provide a ParentViewController which handles that kind of stuff for you. Like hiding/showing navigation bar, adding custom bar items, settings custom titles. Then you can inherit your other VCs from it instead of basic UIViewController, so probably it will be much cleaner and you'll have your navigationBar customization code in one place.